# adding a column with the average calculated from the second, third and fourth highest values

Tags: r, dplyr

Adding a column containing the maximum value is simple

```
df <- df %>% mutate (v.max = max (x))
```

However, I would like to add the average calculated from the 2nd, 3rd, 4th highest value from the x column.
Is there an elegant and concise way to do this?

Something like the following (unfortunately max.k does not appear)

```
df <- df %>% mutate (v.max.mean = mean (max.k(x, 2), max.k(x, 4), max.k(x, 4))
```

Comment: E.g. `avgtopn = \(x, l, k) mean(order(-x)[l:k]); avgtopn(x = df$x, l = 2,  k = 4)` or in your syntax `avgtopn = \(x, l, k) mean(order(-x)[l:k]); df = df |> mutate(v.max.mean = avgtopn(x, 2, 4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With credit to @zephryl's comments:

```r
> df = data.frame(x = c(4, 5, 2, 3, 1))
> avgtop = \(x, l, k) mean(x[order(-x)][l:k])
> df |> dplyr::mutate(v.max.mean = avgtop(x, 2, 4))
  x v.max.mean
1 4          3
2 5          3
3 2          3
4 3          3
5 1          3
```

Answer (score 1):

a pure dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(x = sample(300,10)) |>
   arrange(desc(x)) |>
   mutate(v.max.mean = mean(tail(head(x, 4), 3)))

     x v.max.mean
1  284   248.3333
2  272   248.3333
3  240   248.3333
4  233   248.3333
5  195   248.3333
6  174   248.3333
7  114   248.3333
8   72   248.3333
9   55   248.3333
10  32   248.3333
```